# Nginx configure root domain redirect to subdomain

Tags: nginx

my current setup of webpage is:

forum.xyz.pl

I need xyz.pl redirect to forum.xyz.pl

current nginx.conf:
[nodebb.conf](https://gist.github.com/maciejbak85/158c3445a7df02227d52842890a8e3fd)

I am using aws route53, not sure what value should I put there for root domain also.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

pl to forum.xyz.pl you can simply do:

```
server  {
 server_name xyz.pl;
 rewrite ^ forum.xyz.pl$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This should solve your problem, let me know if you have any other problems. I don't really understand the problem with `Route 53` since it is just handling the DNS entries.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xyz.pl;
    return 301 https://forum.xyz.pl/;
}
server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  forum.xyz.pl;
      #Force Https
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      #listen [::]:80;
      #listen 80;

      server_name forum.xyz.pl;
      ##rest of config goes here
}
```